# PHP array convert ids to count

Tags: php

I am pulling out a list of popular product IDs into an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [popular_product] => 2,60
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [popular_product] => 12,61,60
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [popular_product] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [popular_product] => 9
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [popular_product] => 14
        )

)
```

I want to create a new array that shows me what the most popular products are by count, my approach is this

Combine all popular_product ids into one long comma seperated string like this

```
2,60,12,61,60,2,9,14
```

Is this the most efficient approach?

Comment: Comma seperated strings isn't really a good practice, why don't you just split the id's up? So you get something like ['object'] -> [key] -> [productId]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since php7 you can pass array of **objects** to `array_column`, so it will be something like:

```
print_r(implode(',', array_column($a, 'popular_product')));
```

For php5 you need to use a `foreach` or some `array_` methods, for example:

```
print_r(implode(',', array_reduce($a, function($t,$v) { $t[] = $v->popular_product; return $t; }, [])));
```